# NIFI - Jolt how to select the first non null value in a Json Array

Tags: transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a problem that I am trying to solve in Nifi and would love your help in coming up with a solution. I have thought of using Jolt transform to achieve this, but am open to any other suggestions

I have an Json array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "val1": "AAA",
    "val2": "",
    "val3": "111",
    "val4": "red"
  },
  {
    "val1": "BBB",
    "val2": "2",
    "val3": "222",
    "val4": "blue"
  },
  {
    "val1": "CCC",
    "val2": "",
    "val3": "333",
    "val4": "orange"
  },
  {
    "val1": "DDD",
    "val2": "2",
    "val3": "4444",
    "val4": "green"
  }
]
```

and I wrote a JoltSpec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "val1": "&",
        "val2": "&",
        "val3": "&"
      },
      "0": {
        "val4": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

that transform the json array to:

```
{
  "val4" : "red",
  "val1" : [ "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" ],
  "val2" : [ "2", "", "2" ],
  "val3" : [ "222", "333", "4444" ]
}
```

However, this is not exactly the outcome I am looking for. What I need is for **val2** to be only a single value (I want to ignore all the empty string occurrences and basically select the the first non-empty string that is available.

val2 can either be an empty string "" or some string that occurs repeatedly e.g. "2" (I am using 2 as an example here, but val2 can be anything like 3 or 123 or 345 etc, but if it is 123 all occurrences of val2 will be 123)

Sample desired output

```
{
  "val4" : "red",
  "val1" : [ "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" ],
  "val2" : "2",
  "val3" : [ "222", "333", "4444" ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... silly me.

I used QueryRecord processor and used ORDER BY and then used JoltTransform to select the first record.